# How can I determine how many Cells, or Inchs there are in excel one page

Tags: excel, vba

I want filter and fill some cells before I print these data but before I have to determine where is bottom of page, and where start top of next page. How can I determine?

Comment: Excel is unique in a way, as you can set the print region and also either (a) the zoom factor or (b) on how many pages you want to print that area. In the latter of the two cases Excel calculates automatically which zoom factor to apply (to fit it to the requested pages). So, it pretty much depends on how big / small you want to print things (with which zoom factor). Alternatively, you can (of course) also print everything with a zoom factor of 100%. Yet, chances are that it will look a bit awkward as the pages might get cut at unfortunate places. So, maybe you can elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Of course. I have 800 names in Columns"A" and 1500 SportsTools in Columns"B". Columns"C" contains "A" and "B" connections. Each names have one or more tools and I want an algorithm which prepare the names with connections in advance separate.

First Name
Tools 
Tools 2
Tools 3

PAGEBREAK

Second Name
Tools

PAGEBREAK

Third Name
Tools
Tools 2
Tools 3

Comment: It seems you have not quite understood what I wanted to say. So, I will try to explain with examples. If you have the width of column `A` set to 200 then you'll have problems fitting that on one page (in width). If you furthermore set the height of `A1` to 200 inches then you might not even be able to fit that cell on a sheet. Yet, if you set the zoom factor to 10% then you might even be able to fit a range such as `A1:Z500` on one page. But you will probably need a magnifying glass to read it all.

Comment: I understand you, Thanks you answer!